# Unable to authenticate LDAP with airflow 2,2,3

Tags: ldap, airflow

Airflow: 2.2.3

When user logs in airflow getting following error.

Error message

```
    Python version: 3.6.9
    Airflow version: 2.2.3
    Node: ed11-ss01.aaddsprod.onmicrosoft.com
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
        raise value
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_appbuilder/security/views.py", line 539, in login
        form.username.data, form.password.data
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/airflow/www/fab_security/manager.py", line 992, in auth_user_ldap
        ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_X_TLS_NEWCTX, 0)
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 112, in set_option
        return _ldap_function_call(None,_ldap.set_option,option,invalue)
      File "/datadrive/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ldap/functions.py", line 52, in _ldap_function_call
        result = func(*args,**kwargs)
    ValueError: option error
```

Config used.

```
import os
from airflow import configuration as conf
from flask_appbuilder.security.manager import AUTH_LDAP
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

# Configuration below is described here
# https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/security.html?highlight=ldap#authentication-ldap
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = conf.get('core', 'SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN')

CSRF_ENABLED = True

# customize the name of the builtin roles for Admin and Public accesses
AUTH_ROLE_ADMIN = 'Admin'
AUTH_ROLE_PUBLIC = 'Public'

# allow users to self register
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION = True
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer"

# LDAP Config 
AUTH_TYPE = AUTH_LDAP
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER = 'ldaps://csldap.company.org'
AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False

# search config 
AUTH_LDAP_SEARCH = "DC=cs,DC=msds,DC=company,DC=org"
AUTH_LDAP_UID_FIELD = 'sAMAccountName'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_USER = 'CS\account'
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = 'password'

# role mapping with ad groups. to be implemented
AUTH_LDAP_ALLOW_SELF_SIGNED = True 
AUTH_LDAP_TLS_CACERTFILE = '/etc/airflow/ldap.pem'
```

Above configuration works on previous airflow versions 1.10.6
Changes done on config
AUTH_USER_REGISTRATION_ROLE = "Viewer" (instead of "Admin"

With new install of airflow 2.2.3 (not upgrade) login to airflow UI fails with above error.

Is there anything missing in setup or config for 2.2.3 version ?

Answer (score 0):

You have `AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = False`

When it needs to be:
`AUTH_LDAP_USE_TLS = True`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using ldaps your uri should be `ldaps://csldap.company.org:636`. Assuming you have mounted the cert file on your webserver.for eg.

```
webserver:
  extraVolumes: 
    - name: ldap-cert
      secret:
        secretName: secret-ldap-cert
  extraVolumeMounts:
     - name: ldap-cert
       mountPath: /etc/airflow/ldap.pem
       readOnly: true
```